# Vue.js multiple components not working well with each other

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, vuejs3, vue-component

so I have 2 vue components (ToolBar and ProjectWindow) and 1 view (ProjectsView), The ToolBar is used both in ProjectWindow and in ProjectView.
In the ToolBar I have 2 buttons, one for setting the opacity of a given elemt to 0 (close) and one to set the height of the element to 50px and to move it at the bottom of the screen.
The ProjectWindow is a card that displays some information that it gets through an API call.
And On the ProjectView I have a button in the top right corner (folder).
When I press the folder Button a card is being shown with 3 elements on it (3 of my projects). This card also has the ToolBar element.
When I open the folder card and close it using the toolbar, there's no problem, I can open it back again pressing the folder button. But if I open one of the 3 projects in the ProjectWindow card and close it, I can no longer open the folder card.

- This is ToolBar :

```
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'ToolBar',
    props: {
      card: Object,
      projectWindow: Object,
    },
    data() {
      return {
        isMinimized: false,
      }
    },
    methods: {
      toggleSize() {
        if (this.card) {
          this.card.style.opacity = 10;
          if (this.projectWindow) {
            this.projectWindow.style.opacity = 0;
          }
          this.card.style.transition = "all 0.5s ease-in-out";
          if (this.isMinimized) {
            this.card.style.height = "500px";
          } else {
            this.card.style.marginTop = "auto";
            this.card.style.height = "50px";
            this.card.style.overflow = "hidden";
          }
          this.isMinimized = !this.isMinimized;
        } else {
          console.error("Card element not found");
        }
        if (this.projectWindow) {
          if (this.card) {
            this.card.style.opacity = 0;
          }
          this.projectWindow.style.transition = "all 0.5s ease-in-out";
          if (this.isMinimized) {
            this.card.style.height = "500px";
          } else {
            this.projectWindow.style.marginTop = "auto";
            this.projectWindow.style.height = "50px";
            this.projectWindow.style.overflow = "hidden";
          }
          this.isMinimized = !this.isMinimized
        } else {
          console.error("Project Window not found!")
        }
      },
      close() {
        if (this.card) {
          this.card.style.opacity = 0;
        } else {
          console.error("Card element not found in close func")
          this.$emit('close-project-window')
        }
        if (this.projectWindow) {
          this.projectWindow.style.opacity = 0;
          this.$emit('close-project-window');
        }
      }
    },
  }
</script>

<template>
  <div class="toolbar">
    <h4 v-if="isMinimized" @click="toggleSize" id="maximize" class="bi bi-fullscreen"></h4>
    <h4 v-else @click="toggleSize" id="minimize" class="bi bi-fullscreen-exit"></h4>
    <h4 @click="close" class="bi bi-x-square" style="color: darkred"></h4>
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
  .toolbar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-left: auto;
    gap: 20px;
  }
</style>
```

- This is the ProjectWindow:

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios';
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
import ToolBar from "@/components/ToolBar.vue";

export default {
  name: 'ProjectWindow',
  components: { ToolBar },
  props: {
    slug: String,
  },
  data() {
    return{
      projectWindow: null
    }
  },
  setup(props) {
    const projectData = ref({
      name: null,
      slug: null,
      description: null,
      gitHub: null,
      isHosted: null,
      hostLink: null,
    });

    onMounted(async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(`/api/v1/projects/`);
        const project = response.data.find(p => p.slug === props.slug);

        if (project) {
          projectData.value = {
            name: project.name,
            slug: project.slug,
            description: project.description.replace(/\\n/g, '<br>'),
            gitHub: project.github,
            isHosted: project.is_hosted,
            hostLink: project.host_link,
          };
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    });

    return {
      projectData,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.projectWindow = document.getElementById('projectWindow');
  }
};
</script>

<template>
  <section class="container" id="projectWindow">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h3 class="title">{{ projectData.name }}</h3>
        <ToolBar :project-window="this.projectWindow"/>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body" id="card-body">
        <div class="description" v-html="projectData.description">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer" id="card-footer" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; gap: 10px">
        <a :href="projectData.gitHub" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">GitHub</a>
        <a v-if="projectData.isHosted" :href="projectData.hostLink" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Website Link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>
```

- And this is the ProjectView:

```
<script>
import ProjectWindow from "@/components/ProjectWindow.vue";
import ToolBar from "@/components/ToolBar.vue";

export default {
  name: 'Projects',
  components: {ToolBar, ProjectWindow},
  data() {
    return {
      slug: null,
      isFolderOpen: false,
      card: null,
      projectWindow: null,
      isGameOpen: false,
    }
  },
  watch: {
    isFolderOpen: function () {
      this.card.style.opacity = 1;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    openGame(slug) {
      this.projectWindow = document.getElementById('projectWindow');
      this.card.style.opacity = 10;
      if (this.projectWindow) {
        this.projectWindow.style.opacity = 10;
      } else {
        console.error("No project window in project view")
      }
      this.slug = slug
      this.isGameOpen = !this.isGameOpen
    },
    openFolder() {
      this.card.style.opacity = 1;
      this.isFolderOpen = !this.isFolderOpen
      console.log(this.isFolderOpen)
    },
    closeProjectWindow() {
      this.isGameOpen = false
      this.card = document.getElementById('card');
      console.log(this.card)
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.card = document.getElementById('card');
  }
};
</script>

<template>
  <div class="side-container">
    <div v-if="isFolderOpen"><i class="bi bi-folder2-open" @click="openFolder"></i></div>
    <div v-else><i class="bi bi-folder2" @click="openFolder"></i></div>
  </div>
  <div id="projectWindow">
    <ProjectWindow :slug="this.slug" v-if="isGameOpen"/>
  </div>
  <section class="games container" id="card">
    <div class="card"  v-if="isFolderOpen">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h3 class="title">Games</h3>
        <ToolBar :card="card" :project-window="projectWindow" @close-project-window="closeProjectWindow()"/>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body" id="card-body">
        <div class="game">
          <label for="shoot">Shoot The Crow</label>
          <div id="shoot"><i class="bi bi-bullseye" style="color: red" @click="openGame('shootthecrow')"></i></div>
        </div>
        <div class="game">
          <label for="guess">Guess The Number</label>
          <div id="guess"><i class="bi bi-patch-question" style="color: green" @click="openGame('guessthenumber')">
          </i></div>
        </div>
        <div class="game">
          <label for="pig">The Pig Game</label>
          <div id="pig"><i class="bi bi-dice-5-fill" style="color: mediumpurple" @click="openGame('piggame')"></i></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>
```

Thank you for taking the time to read this. I no longer know what to try.

I tried passing the ProjectWindow to the TooBar component as an html object but that only stopped it for working

Comment: Have you looked in the browser developer tools console?

Comment: I saw your confused logic,the projectWindow was always null before you openGame, so I suggest you learning the vue render timing, then you wont use document api in vue